# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-data-validation (from versions: none)

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

I get this error with `Python 3.7` and `Windows 10 64-bit` (which is supported).
It seems that there are only wheels for Windows for Python 3.5 and 3.6...

Thanks in advance.

```
pip install tensorflow-data-validation
```

> Collecting tensorflow-data-validation
>   Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-data-validation (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-data-validation

### Software and versions

-Windows 10 Enterprise. 64-bit
-import sys
!{sys.executable} --version
Python 3.7.3
(Python 3.7 version (Anaconda 2019.07 for Windows Installer https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ , Jupyter Notebook))
-Successfully installed pip-19.2.3 (pip --version)
-ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall. (pip install apache-beam)
-Successfully installed tensorboard-1.14.0 tensorflow-1.14.0 tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0 (pip install tensorflow)
-Successfully installed pyarrow-0.14.0 (pip install pyarrow==0.14.*)
-https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/install  (https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-data-validation/)
Supported platforms
TFDV is tested on the following 64-bit operating systems:
Windows 7 or later.

### verbose

pip install -v tensorflow-data-validation
Collecting tensorflow-data-validation
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow-data-validation/
    Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
    Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
[…]
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp35-cp35m-win_amd64: files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/a1/b1f0c9c88713a60f206cf7bfaeb9391da1c9c8e3a6c98cd22078568777db/tensorflow_data_validation-0.14.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=eeff482c69ae1e49d84bbbef7c2ca058735e1d12cd640b643853f5f5fb05bc70 (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,<4)
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp36-cp36m-win_amd64: files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/75/f3112982ca379481ae7706a94bf2755bd886fd4c8386e88ab978c5a0ae52/tensorflow_data_validation-0.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=611c23f718df87dcb6f34a6cf81d1a9699523254803607537e3d7e94e2c4712c (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,<4)
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp35-cp35m-win_amd64: files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/13/d0a90ccde514a4547b5d2ce3268f683aa6d5fb9f185c2b4d9a7db15eafca/tensorflow_data_validation-0.14.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=df5eb52ef53ee9db901aed5a30db183f272cda0a8b4f6981d9843cb6c52fc58a (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,<4)
Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp36-cp36m-win_amd64: files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/3e/dec2c051d4a6dd04dcacfd73d4d02be3ad3cd56008ba2251e3bd8cc36adf/tensorflow_data_validation-0.14.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=2cba18c385d7de8d346b8db4b9bfec38e8535e1371a6a7f2f375ea51264dfeb8 (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,<4)
[…]
  Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'tensorflow-data-validation': discarding no candidates

### PyPI Download Files

tensorflow_data_validation-0.14.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB) 
Wheel cp35 Aug 22, 2019
tensorflow_data_validation-0.14.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.7 MB) 
Wheel cp36 Aug 22, 2019
-https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-data-validation/#modal-close

Answer (score 1):

Works with Python 3.6.9 (e.g. Anaconda Navigator>Environments>Create)